# Form.PixelsPerInch no longer used in Delphi Tokyo

Tags: delphi, highdpi

In older Delphi's (for example Delphi XE4), it is clear what the `Form.PixelsPerInch` property is for. If I change this property and save the form, close and then reload it, all controls and fonts on the form will be resized accordingly.

However, in Delphi Tokyo (maybe since Seattle) making such a change has no effect on the controls on the form, and seems to serve no purpose.

Is this correct?

If Delphi Tokyo is not using the PixelsPerInch property I wonder how it can correctly scale the form at different DPI's..

Comment: AFAIK is PixelsPerInch taken from the DPI at design time. This is backed by the fact that it is the value returned by GetDesignDpi.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You can enter a value, and it will be saved and not changed by the IDE. However it makes no difference.