# How PixelsPerInch works in Delphi 10.3 Rio?

Tags: delphi, dpi, delphi-10.3-rio

I do not understand what is the purpose of `PixelsPerInch` property... It seems it is useless. If `Scaled` is checked, `PixelsPerInch` cannot be modified. If `Scaled` is unchecked and `PixelsPerInch` is changed, the form size an font is scaled to a fixed value, regardless of the value you entered in `PixelsPerInch` field. Of course, I checked the form size at runtime.

Comment: I don't understand the question. PixelsPerInch works the same in Rio as it did in Seattle or Berlin or Delphi 2007 or Delphi 7.

Comment: I just wanted to mention the version...

Comment: The problem is that the form is not scaled to another size (at runtime) when I change the PixelsPerInch value (at design time).

Comment: @KenWhite, look ! There is another user with the same problem, so I gues I am not crazy... The `PixelsPerInch` it seems is no longer used in the new versions of Delphi. These new versions behave like `PixelsPerInch` is fixed at 96 regardless of the value you enter...   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54742794/form-pixelsperinch-no-longer-used-in-delphi-tokyo

Answer (score 0):

**Scaled is True**

In the dfm file the `PixelsPerInch` property contains the screen DPI value used when the form was designed. This is necessary in order to be able to scale control position and size values to different DPI screens at runtime.

**Scaled is False**

The `PixelsPerInch` property is ignored and control position and size values are used unscaled.

Comment: But then why does it have any effect if I change the PixelsPerInch value when Scaled is True ? Shouldn't form be scaled to another dimension ?

Comment: What do you mean by "why does it have any effect?"

Comment: The form is not scaled to another size (at runtime) when I change the PixelsPerInch value (at design time).

Comment: No. But then the IDE doesn't have any pretence to offer such a service.

Comment: But that doesn't make sense. If I can't control the scale ratio of my form, PixelsPerInch is useless... If Delphi scale the form to a fixed ratio known only by itself, then PixelsPerInch can by removed, as it is not used...

Comment: It's used when the form is Scaled at runtime. And when it is Scaled at design time when you open the form on a screen with a DPI that differs from that in the dfm file.

Comment: So in order to scale at runtime you need this equation: `pos_rt = pos_dt * dpi_rt / dpi_dt` where `dt` is design time and `rt` is runtime. The `dt` values are stored in the dfm file, `dpi_rt` is obtained at runtime by asking the system.

Comment: I still don't get it... Delphi help states that "Changes to PixelsPerInch made in the Object Inspector only affect the form at runtime." I do that and nothing changes at runtime !

Comment: Certainly does impact runtime for me. You can see that it must by inspecting the equation in my previous comment. Make the edit by editing the dfm file directly in a text editor.